# Can I think of trigonometric expressions like this?

Tags: trigonometry

This expression I.e

$\frac{\sin^2 A}{\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)} + \frac{\cos^2A}{\sin A(\cos A-\sin A)}$ is also written as :

$\frac{\sin^2 A}{\cos A(\sin A-\cos A)} - \frac{\cos^2A}{\sin A(\sin A-\cos A)}$

So , to understand why this is true ; I used was arithmetic numbers

$\frac{2^2 A}{3(2-3)} + \frac{3^2A}{2(3-2)}$ and similarly for the other one. And since I can easily calculate the equation using arithmetic numbers. I got both the equations equal.

But for some equation , this way does not work. For example ,

$o=\cot A , c=\cos A$.

Equation is : $\frac{o*c}{o+c}$ = $\frac{o-c}{o*c}$ .

Inserting numbers inside these o & c + cross multiplying both the sides. I get that both the sides are equal. $(oc)^2 ≠ (o-c)(o+c)$

What is the other way I can solve these type of equations or should I continue this way ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Associating numbers with trigonometric functions can be done, but it needs to be done in such a way that the new numbers reflect all the properties of trigonometric functions. You were just lucky in your first case.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have done all of it sir. Where do I need to edit ?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 What do I need to do ?

Comment: Now it's much better, but I would use $\times$ instead of $*$ for multiplication.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok sir. Would be grateful to know your views about my Q.

Comment: I think you are confused of the difference between a mathematical expression and an equation. In the second case you are asked to **find** the variable(s) that verify that equation. So $2x=2x^2$ is only valid for $x=0$ or $x=1$